# Unable to inject clicks while testing an Android application

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

While using an Android testing framework (e.g. Espresso, Robotium), all my tests are failing with this kind of warnings in the logcat.

> W/InputDispatcher(61): Permission denied: injecting event from pid 123 uid 10001
>   W/WindowManager(61): Input event injection failed.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I fixed the issue by adding the following tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of the app under test.

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Although this tag is not required for the app to run, without it the automated tests are prevented from injecting click events.